# ifconfig showing twice a virtual interface

Tags: interface, virtual, ifconfig

Facing the following situation when creating a virtual interface through a kernel module
with name **vlan1.1** and then assign an IP address to it.
More specifically, when the virtual interface is alone and no other one is present with
name **vlan1.Y** everything looks OK with ifconfig output.
After performing the following steps I face the below strange output when issuing **ifconfig**:

1. Create **vlan1.100** and assign an IP address to it 10.1.4.1/24
2. Create **vlan1.1** and assign an IP address to it 192.168.1.1/24
3. **vlan1.1** is shown twice with the second appearance not containing any statistics

   vlan1.1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
   inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
   RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
   TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
   collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
   RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:738 (738.0 b)

   vlan1.100       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
   inet addr:10.1.4.1  Bcast:10.1.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
   RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
   TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
   collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
   RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:738 (738.0 b)

   vlan1.1         Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
   inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

Can you please inform me what could be the root cause of it?
Please mind that **ip link show** shows each interface only once.

Comment: Found what the problem was. It was an old version used for net-tools package and when used version 2.10 everything was OK.